# How to search GitHub user with location has space

Tags: javascript, ajax, github

The request to GitHub Api is as simple as

https://api.github.com/search/users?q=+location:Hong%20Kong&page=1&per_page=100

By this request, I would like to find out the current GitHub user who is  in "Hong Kong".

But the result return is not as expected,it doesn't return my colleagues GitHub results. If I change "Hong Kong" to "HK", the result is fine. Are there are any space character is not represent as %20 in their web request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably encapsulate the location in quotation-marks: "Hong Kong".

```
https://api.github.com/search/users?q=+location:%22Hong%20Kong%22&page=1&per_page=100
```

(Where `%22` is the URl-encoded form of `"`)